# How does Youtube bypass Chrome and Firefox's Autoplay blocker?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

About a year ago Chrome, then Firefox, introduced a new policy for blocking autoplay videos and audio.

There is currently a few ways to bypass audio anti-autoplay, but there doesn't seem to be any way of bypassing Chrome and Firefox's video anti-autoplay, expect for Youtube and many handfuls of websites still showing video ads at the highest volume possible.

Is there a solution, server side, I can do to where I am able to play a video onLoad without having the client manually turn it off the feature in chrome/firefox?

and is it possible to use iframe to start the video on load?

Answer (score 0):

They are whitelisted.
Here is blog post where they admit that there is a whitelist of pages https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/, which is imho very unfair and discriminates competition. For those non-listed here are rules: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/